# C# ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have a scenario here whereby when a user wants to reset a password, the system will have to send a temporary random generated password to the user by email. I tried storing the temporary password into a new column in the database but I am not really sure about whether this approach works well. Some people recommend using `token` such as below:

```
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

However, I am really new to `ASP.NET`  and I am not familiar with `token`. How do I compare the temporary generated `token` with the `token` in the database?

Another method that I found to implement this is to have a `Membership.GeneratePassword` function that generates a random string of characters:

```
model.temppwd = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 1);
```

Can anybody provide me an ideal way to implement this functionality with some example? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: In fact, the ASP.NET Web Application project template contains a full implementation

Comment: @Joe you don't need to store anything. The token is *not* a temporary password and *you* don't need to store it anywhere. This is taken care of by ASP.NET Identity just as user/password storage is. In the ASP.NET MVC project template you'll see that AccountController has a ResetPassword method that calls `var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password)` where `model.Code` is the token entered by the user either directly or through a link

Answer (score 0):

In our project we used

`Guid.NewGuid();` 
and sent the email containing the link to the recover password action (MVC) as a query string: `https://yoursite.com/account/reset/?code=your_guid_code`

Example:

```
ResetPassword resetPassword = new resetPassword();
resetPassword.Code = Guid.NewGuid();
string strLink = string.Format("{0}", actionUrl + "?code="+ resetPassword.Code);`
```

And now you can use the `strLink` to send with your e-mail. You'll need to store the Guid in a database table alongside with the userId, so that you can implement the resetting procedure. When the user clicks the link from your email he'll get in a form / view that asks for a new password. Also you'll want to add an extra column to that table in order to provide an expiration limit for that code. If the user clicks the link in the e-mail and the code expired you'll have to inform the user and send another e-mail with another code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way I can implement it by providing the user a random password for the user to log in and change their password?

Comment: I think it adds one extra step. You could provide a random password, sure, but it's not very useful since it will have to change it anyway. Instead you can add a boolean property to your class / model such as "MustChangePasswordOnLogin", and set it to true when the app sends the e-mail. When the user is following the link in the e-mail, check the property. If it's false, that means he accidentally clicked it again, so load a default view. After the user changes his password, set the property to false, and you're done and you could also reuse this schema when creating new accounts.